# Sequentially numbering MongoDB subdocuments

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection of "departments" and each department has a sub-collection of "tickets". In the old MySQL-based system, we assigned a number to each ticket (per department) by counting existing records and adding one.

This gives each department a human-readable numbering system to identify tickets: 1, 2, 3, etc.

However, in Mongo, auto increment fields like this aren't used and I'm finding that because operations may be async (using Mongoose in a NodeJS app), counting existing records may not be trustworthy (same with incrementing a counter on the department collection)

I've spent time looking for a solution but am finding it difficult to sort out unrelated topics.

Is there any trusted way to make a sequential number system that relies on a custom query?

Here's an example of the models/save code I'm toying with

```
var OrganizationSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    departments: [Department.schema]
});
var DepartmentSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

// Tickets aren't stored as subdocuments in Departments because there could be
// a lot, I didn't want it to affect performance
var TicketSchema = new Schema({
    project: {
        type: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Department' }],
        required: true
    },
    summary: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});


// in-progress save code
Organization.findOne({ 'departments._id': department }, function(err, org){

    var lastTicketId = org.departments[0].lastTicketId;
    console.log(lastTicketId);

    var ticket = new Ticket({
        department: department,
        summary: req.body.summary
    });

    ticket.save(function(err, result) {

        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }

        Organization.findOneAndUpdate(
            { 'departments._id': department },
            { $inc: { 'departments.$.lastTicketId': 1 } },
            function(err, result) {
                console.log('saving ' + result.departments[0].lastTicketId);
            }
        );
    });
});
```

This save code is an API endpoint, so I'm bulk-testing 20-some API requests from a `for` loop. That means they're coming in very fast and I can really see the async effect on the numbering.

The console.log output is:

```
loading 0
loading 0
saving 0
loading 1
loading 1
loading 1
loading 1
loading 1
loading 1
loading 1
saving 1
saving 2
loading 1
loading 1
loading 1
loading 1
loading 1
loading 1
loading 1
loading 1
loading 1
loading 1
loading 1
loading 1
loading 1
loading 1
loading 1
loading 1
loading 1
loading 1
saving 3
saving 4
saving 9
saving 5
saving 10
saving 6
saving 11
saving 7
saving 12
saving 17
saving 8
saving 13
saving 18
saving 23
saving 14
saving 19
saving 24
saving 15
saving 20
saving 25
saving 16
saving 21
saving 22
```

Comment: If you are using Mongoose, each subdocument gets an `_id` automatically. You can also get the creation date from an ID so that would tell you in which order they were created if that's what you want.

Comment: I realize each subdoc has an ObjectID, but this numbering system is for people, not code. I'll internally always rely on the _id, but when people interact with the application, they're not going to want to refer to tickets based on them - they need a number that's memorable and can by typed.

Comment: I somehow have the feeling that there is something wrong with your modeling. Can you show some examples of your data?

Comment: Maybe you're right, but the fact that the documents are being saved asynchronously means the number isn't going to be correct depending on the order.

Comment: I've updated the ticket with model/save code I'm toying with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the question was a little incorrect because I had assumed mongo was the issue. However, in reviewing the logs I posted, I realized that eventually the numbers were being incremented correctly, so my problem had to be a javascript issue.

I figured that querying the last ID, then saving the ticket, then updating the last ID was too inefficient, but must be allowing room for async queries to overlap.

I decided to rewrite the save logic to validate the ticket without saving it, then increment the last ID in a single query, and then save the issue with the proper value.

So far it appears to work perfectly.

```
// Ensure validation passes before we increment an ID
// so we avoid disconnected IDs if it fails later
ticket.validate(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    }

    // Find and update last ID in one transaction
    // due to async issues
    Organization.findOneAndUpdate(
        { 'departments._id': department },
        { $inc: { 'departments.$.lastTicketId': 1 } },
        function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }

            ticket.displayId = result.departments[0].lastTicketId;
            ticket.save(function(err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                }
                // success
            });
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 possible techniques with mongoDB

1. a counters collection
2. optimistic loop

[see mongoDB article here:](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/#auto-increment-counters-collection)

something that is not mentioned in this article is that counter's collection guarantees a unique incremental id in a multiprocess environment but if this id is used for insertions insertion order is not 100% guaranteed to correspond to this id.
If insertion order is critical use the Optimistic Loop technique

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Mongoose, you could try auto-increment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-auto-increment

```
var OrganizationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
});
var DepartmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
});

var TicketSchema = new Schema({
    ticketNumber: { type: Number, required: true },
    project: {
        type: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Department' }],
        required: true}],
    ...
});

TicketSchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, {model: 'Ticket', field: 'ticketNumber'} );
```

This will auto increment the ticketNumber each time you insert a ticket document. It's not incremented per department though - just a unique number per ticket.

The latest ticket number is stored in a special document collection in MongoDB `mongoose-auto-increments` so no problems with picking the next number even if you're in a web farmed multi server situation.

Be careful if inserting Ticket documents manually though. You would need to manually update the `mongoose-auto-increments` collection too.